# IIS Redirecting Font requests to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

Were attempting to deploy an ASP.net MVC  application 
everything in the Content folders serves fine except our font files 
which seem to be redirecting to the login page 
i have tried using

```
  <location path="Content" allowOverride="false">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
       </system.web>
    </location>
```

and have check that the mime-types are set correctly

i have also tried adding a web.config to the Content folder with the same results

we are using the bundling feature for our css and js code so this may be part of why they work

we are serving the application with Forms Authentication and Anonymous authentication turned on at the the application root in IIS as wel

[image]